# Getting Checked property from CheckBox when Command is called in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid of CheckBoxes in a WPF C# project. Each CheckBox's `Command` property is bound to a `CheckBoxChangedCommand` in my WView.xaml file, like so:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="true" x:Name ="CheckBox0" 
          Command="{Binding CheckBoxChangedCommand}" />
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="true" x:Name="CheckBox1" 
          Command="{Binding CheckBoxChangedCommand}" />
```

Each time one of the CheckBoxes is either checked or unchecked, I call `CheckBoxChanged`. How would I go about displaying a pop-up window showing either 1. the row number in the grid of the CheckBox and the name of the CheckBox ("CheckBox0", for example) and 2. The Checked value (true/false) for the checkbox?

My CheckBoxChangedCommand, in WViewModel.cs file, looks like this:

```
public ICommand CheckBoxChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(param =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBoxChanged!"); 
        });
    }
}
```

How can I access the `IsChecked` property and the row number of the CheckBox that triggered `CheckBoxChanged` from within`CheckBoxChanged`? How can I pass the data from my View to my ViewModel?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't bind the IsChecked property to your ViewModel, like this: `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"`; this would have the advantage that you are informed when the user changes the checkbox's state and you know its value at the same time. (Works best if you have one ViewModel per checkbox.)

Comment: I tried making a separate `IsCheckedX` handler for each of my 3 CheckBoxes (1 through X). How would I get the current state of the CheckBox inside `IsCheckedX`? I tried using `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked2}"`, where `IsChecked2` is a void function that simply displays a MessageBox that says hello, but this function is never called when I check and uncheck CheckBox 2.

Comment: You cannot bind to a method; `IsChecked2` must be a public property, like `public bool IsChecked2 { get { ... } set { ... } }`.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to do more with binding here.

First of all, you should probably be binding the IsChecked property of your Checkboxes to a property on your viewmodel.

Second, based on your comment about needing to know the row number of the checkbox that was checked, I'd say you probably need to be generating the "row" including the CheckBox via databinding, so that you can then pass the object that represents the row as the CommandParameter to your CheckBoxChangedCommand.

So something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

and then in your resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItemType}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
              Command="{Binding CheckChangedCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

*Note: Your CheckChangedCommand is probably on the main ViewModel, not the item-level ViewModel, so you probably need to do some  other type of lookup to make it find it - this example is just for simplicity*